# How to hide Accordions on page load?

Tags: jquery

I have two sets of JQuery Accordions within a single DIV tag. At the moment when the page loads both these Accordions are displayed one below the other. However, I only want one of these Accordions to be displayed when the HTML page loads. How can I hide one while making the other one visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them different identifiers, and use a selector to select the one you want to hide and change its visible property to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

from css:

```
display:none;
```

or

```
visibility:hidden;
```

or

```
position:absolute;left:-9999px;
```

or

```
opacity:0
```

This is to hide the accordion COMPLETLY. But if you want to show only accordion heads, then hide only contents (dd or div or whatever did you use) with `display:none`.